# what is the difference between create temp table and create table #temp?

Tags: amazon-redshift

What is the difference between SQL statements

- `create temp table temp_1` And
- `create table #temp_1`
  used in creating temporary table or are both the same ?

Comment: The first one is valid for Postgres the second one is not.

Comment: @ranjani-r Please Clear your Question about SQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm able to run both the statement starting with "create table #temp" and "create temp table temp1" using POSTGRESQL and they yield same results.

Comment: Then you are not using Postgres (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8503df2115b38422dcb892664bb49fab)) - maybe some fork. What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: Repeating @a_horse_with_no_name: then you are not using Postgres. See Postgres documentation [Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), note the 2nd paragraph. You could enclose the table name is double quotes ,that has issues of its own and should be avoided, but if do it creates a permanent table named  '#temp", **not a  temporary** table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, both syntax does the same work !!

**Users can either use the temp keyword or a # sign right before the table name to create a temporary table (Redshift Temp Table). In other words, to create a Redshift Temp Table, simply specify the TEMPORARY keyword (or TEMP abbreviation) or # sign in your CREATE TABLE DDL statement.**

syntax 1 : `CREATE TABLE #table_name (column_name1 data_type1,column_name2 data_typ2);`

Syntax 2: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_name (column_name1 data_type1,column_name2 data_typ2);`

Syntax 3: `CREATE TEMP TABLE table_name (column_name1 data_type1,column_name2 data_typ2);`

Supporting documents on same -->

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html
2. https://hevodata.com/learn/redshift-temp-tables/#c2